# JavaScript Reference Several Images With Similar Names Without Linking to Each One

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, arrays

I have the following code which chooses a background image depending from the images array. The problem is that I have about 200 images and I was hoping there would be a quicker way to put all of them in the images array than have to list each image like I have the six currently. They have very similar names (i.e. image001, image002, ... image200) so if somehow the number could just be added onto the "image".

This would save me a lot of time and space. The code is below.

```
var images = [
'image0.png',
'image1.png',
'image2.png',
'image3.png',
'image4.png',
'image5.png'
];

$("#container").on("scroll", function(){
var $container = $("#container");
var $content = $("#content");
var totalScrollAmount = $content.height() - $container.height();
var percentScrolled = $container.scrollTop() / totalScrollAmount;
$content.css({
    background:"url("+images[Math.floor(percentScrolled * images.length)]+")"
});
});
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var images = [];
for(var i = 0; i < 200; i++)
  images.push("image" + ("000" + i).substr(-3, 3) + ".png");
```

Comment: that seems simple. Could I just put that inside the array without having to change anything else in the code and my code would function exactly like if I linked to all the images separately?

Answer (score 0):

Here is a generator written as an *IIFE*

```
var images = (function (maxlen, arr, i) {
    function pad3(i) { // helper
        return ('000' + i).slice(-3);
    }
    arr || (arr = []); // defaults
    i || (i = 0);
    arr.length = maxlen;
    for (; i < maxlen; ++i) { // do the loop
        arr[i] = 'image' + pad3(i) + '.png';
    }
    return arr;
}(3)); // 3 for 3 items

images; // ["image000.png", "image001.png", "image002.png"]
```